# Java locking simple multi threaded queue class to avoid starvation

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I'm currently reviewing concurrency and wanted to double check my understanding.

Let's say I have a simple queue class that I want to use multiple threads to take jobs off of the queue and run.

```java
class JobQueue {
    static Queue<Job> jobq;
    ExecutorService exec;

    public void addJob(Job j) 
        synchronized(jobq) {
            jobq.add(j)
        }
    
    public void runJob() {
      synchronized(jobq) {
         while (!jobq.isEmpty()) {
             exec.submit(() -> jobq.poll().run());
         }
      }
    }
```

Pardon my syntax I quickly put this together. Anyways, I have a 2 part question.

1. To avoid starvation of the `addJob` method, would it be better to lock the `!jobq.isEmpty()` and then unlock, and then separately lock the `exec.submit...`? That way in between checking the jobq is empty and polling a job off, the `addJob` has a chance to acquire the lock?
2. If the above is the case (it's better to unlock after the `while` check), how would you do so with this synchronized object? Since the `exec.submit` is nested within the `while` loop which is nested within the `synchronized(jobq)` loop.

Comment: Your code seems overly complicated. What is the purpose of `JobQueue`? If `exec` is a thread pool, then it already has a queue of its own. Why can't you just submit jobs directly to the pool? If there is some reason why you can't let them start working until some gating event happens (whatever it is that calls `runJob()` in your existing code,) then you can have them wait for the gate to open before they begin to do whatever it is that they do.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. To avoid starvation of the `addJob` method, would it be better to lock the `!jobq.isEmpty()` and then unlock, and then separately lock the `exec.submit...`? That way in between checking the jobq is empty and polling a job off, the `addJob` has a chance to acquire the lock?

In this case locking the whole `while{...}` loop is OK because `exec.submit...` doesn't do much: it actually only creates and returns a `Future`, while the task is executed in another thread.

---

Also if `!jobq.isEmpty()` and `exec.submit...` were locked separately, then you would get an additional problem: what if in between these locks another thread executes `runJob()` and `jobq` becomes empty.

Comment: There’s another problem in the original code: because `jobq.poll()` is deferred to the executor, it is not executing within the synchronized block. It runs on another thread at a later time and does not hold the lock on `jobq`.